# Trouble updating the database using sqlite on iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have the code working to open the database. And I populate a table view. Then when the table view item is clicked it launches the details page. In this details page there is a button then when pressed I need to update the database. While debugging all the checks seem to work but when I view my database I can see nothing has changed. I'm very unfamiliar with getting the UPDATE statement to work so I'm sure something is wrong. Anything will help here's the code:

```
sqlite3 *database;

NSString *databasePath;

databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mydatabase" ofType:@"sql"];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *sql1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
            sql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE tablename SET isComplete= '1' WHERE name= '%@';", self.detailItem.nameOfItem];
            const char *sql = [sql1  UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, 1, &stmt, NULL);

            sqlite3_step(stmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
```

I also have this function in the delegate file, that I think checks for a copy and shouldn't it be making a writable db in the user files?

Okay I've updated my databasePath to pull from the documents, not the resources. But I just can't see where it's going wrong.

here is the create database function and the databasepath variable before it:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    //[fileManager release];
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step`. Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to get the error if there is one.

Comment: And the most important issue is that files in the app's resource bundle are read-only.

Comment: Well shoot if it's read only, I'm going to have to figure out how to store the data...

Comment: That issue has been covered a lot. You need to copy the read-only db from the app bundle to a writable folder then always use that copy.

Comment: Well then I'd like to know how to copy the database to the documents folder, since I didn't know that existed. And how to access the knew database and not accidentally the old one